# How to automatically add counted number to navigation menu items?

Tags: functions, menus, navigation

In my website I need a navigation menu to show arrangement of my posts. So I need the navigation menu to count the items and display the number of every item as a label before the title of that item. I think we need a `foreach` in  `wp_get_nav_menu_items` to count but I don't know exactly the way.
I need something like this from that menu:
1- title one
2- title two
3- title three
4- ...

I have the following codes but I have two issues:
1- I do not know why it does not work?
2- I need a class as `.current-menu-item` to find the current item in other items. this class is as a default class in wordpresss menu but I can not do that.

```
// Get the nav menu based on $menu_name (same as 'theme_location' or 'menu' arg to wp_nav_menu)
// This code based on wp_nav_menu's code to get Menu ID from menu slug
$menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';

if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

    menu_count = 0;
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        $menu_count++;
        $menu_list .= '<li><span>'.$menu_count.'</span><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
    $menu_list .= '</ul>';
} else {
    $menu_list = '<ul><li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li></ul>';
}
// $menu_list now ready to output
```

Thanks a lot to helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, I found out it myself:
this tested menu supports sub menu, submenu will have arrow. also current page parent and menu item will have active class. you're wellcome :)

```
function our_custom_menu( $menu_name ) {

//$menu_name = 'header-menu';

if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    $menu_list = '';
    $count = 0;
    menuitem_count == 0;
    $submenu = false;$cpi=get_the_id();
    foreach( $menu_items as $current ) {
        if($cpi == $current->object_id ){if ( !$current->menu_item_parent ) {$cpi=$current->ID;}else{$cpi=$current->menu_item_parent;}$cai=$current->ID;break;}
    }
    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        $link = $menu_item->url;
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $menuitem_count++;
        $menu_item->ID==$cai ? $ac2=' current_menu' : $ac2='';
        if ( !$menu_item->menu_item_parent ) {
            $parent_id = $menu_item->ID;$parent_id==$cpi ? $ac=' current_item' : $ac='';
            if(!empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) && $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent == $parent_id ){ //Checking has child
                $menu_list .= '<li class="dropdown has_child'.$ac.'"><span>'.$menuitem_count.'</span><a href="'.$link.'" class="dropdown-toggle'.$ac2.'" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="nav-span"></span>'.$title.'<span class="caret"></span></a>';
            }else{
                $menu_list .= '<li class="'.$ac.'">' ."\n";$menu_list .= '<span>'.$menuitem_count.'</span><a href="'.$link.'" class="'.$ac2.'">'.$title.'</a>' ."\n";
            }

        }
        if ( $parent_id == $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) {
            if ( !$submenu ) {
                $submenu = true;
                $menu_list .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' ."\n";
            }
            $menu_list .= '<li class="item">' ."\n";
            $menu_list .= '<a href="'.$link.'" class="'.$ac2.'">'.$title.'</a>' ."\n";
            $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";
            if(empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) || $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu){
                $menu_list .= '</ul>' ."\n";
                $submenu = false;
            }
        }
        if (empty($menu_items[$count + 1]) || $menu_items[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ) { 
            $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";      
            $submenu = false;
        }
        $count++;
    }
} else {
    $menu_list = '<li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li>';
}

echo $menu_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `menu_count = 0;` before your `foreach` and then within your `foreach` you'll need to include `$menu_count++;` and then you could add `$menu_count` as an attribute, or a label.

You will need to make a custom function for this, so be sure to check out the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) on `wp_get_nav_menu_items`

Comment: thanks my friend. I updated the question. please check it if you can fix it. thanks again

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing more of your code, but I think you might have it in the wrong place. You need to define your menu in a function and return that menu in order for it to output like you're hoping. You should also be able to snag from the codex the objects that apply the classes you're looking for. I would say You need to take a closer look at this - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/#source

Comment: I wrote the answer. Thanks for all :)